# Array variables didn't get allocated in a data section when I gave section attribute, why?

Tags: c, linker

I have added attribute specifying the section for some data (outside any function, so it's in a kind of data section) as below.

```
char __attribute__(( aligned(256), __section__(".axpudata") )) mem_local  [N_AXEMIS_PER_AXPU][LOCAL_SEGMENT_SIZE];
char __attribute__(( aligned(256), __section__(".axpudata") )) mem_private[N_AXEMIS_PER_AXPU][N_AXEC_PER_AXEMIS*N_THREAD_PER_AXEC][PRIVATE_SEGMENT_SIZE];
uint64_t  __attribute__(( aligned(256), __section__(".axpudata") )) mem_knlargs[KNLARGS_SEGMENT_SIZE/8];
struct __attribute__(( aligned(256), __section__(".axpudata") )) es_t      axpu_es   [N_AXEMIS_PER_AXPU];
struct __attribute__(( aligned(256), __section__(".axpudata") )) reg_csr_t axpu_regs [N_AXEMIS_PER_AXPU];
```

But when I examine the map file, I found mem_local, mem_private, mem_knlargs were all allocated at  '.axpudata' section but axpu_es and axpu_regs were allocated at '.bss' section. I then found axpu_es and axpu_regs didn't have to be at the '.axpudata' section and it doesn't  cause any problem if they are in '.bss' section. Buy I'm curious why they didn't get allocated in the '.axpudata' section. In what cases does this kind of thing happen?
Here is the part of the linker script about this.

```
  .axpudata : {
    . = ALIGN(65536);
    *(.axpudata)
  }

  /* Uninitialized data */
  . = ALIGN(0x10000);
  .bss :
  {
    __bss_start = .;
    __bss_start__ = .;
    *(.bss*)
    __bss_end = .;
    __bss_end__ = .;
  }
```

ADD :
I just found the attribute was given between struct and es_t like `struct __attribute__(..) es_t axpu_es[..]` but it should be `struct es_t __attribute__(..) axpu_es[...]`.

Comment: Please try `__attribute__(....) struct stuff var;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later found the attribute was given between struct and es_t like `struct __attribute__(..) es_t axpu_es[..]` but it should be `struct es_t __attribute__(..) axpu_es[...]`. When I fixed this, 'axpu_es' and 'axpu_regs' array got allocated in '.axpudata' section.

Answer (score 0):

The first part specifies [attributes for variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.1/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html).

The second part specifies [attributes for types](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.1/gcc/Type-Attributes.html#Type%20Attributes), which doesn't include a `__section__` option.

So, apparently you can specify that a specific variable should reside in a section, but not that all variables of a type should do that.

Comment: Oh I just found the attribute was given between struct and es_t like `struct __attribute__(..) es_t axpu_es[..]` but it should be `struct es_t __attribute__(..) axpu_es[...]`.